# Database Connection Error?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am trying to connect a database named `DailyRoutine`. My SQL file stored in the same file as Java source files. Here is my code section:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://DailyRoutine";
try {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication2.class.getName())
        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

What is the problem here? Where should I store SQL file?

Comment: What is the problem indeed? What error are you getting?

Comment: SQL file? You don't have an "SQL file" if you're connecting to a MySQL database. What exactly do you mean by "SQL file"?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to execute some SQL (from a file) against that connection?

Comment: i created my database by using php my admin and export. And when i export this it created .sql. I tried to open this database in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded the JDBC driver?

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://DailyRoutine";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```